# Decode a format of string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, decode

like title, I have a string format like this:

```
<7b0a2020 22536372 65656e49 4422203a 20224c61 6e64696e 67506167 65564322 2c0a2020 22446576 69636549 4422203a 20224537 45463844 43452d43 4538412d 34463043 2d424243 352d4630 38304332 39464546 3239222c 0a202022 53657373 696f6e53 74617274 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 222c0a20 20225365 7373696f 6e456e64 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 220a7d>
```

Please let me know what this format is, and how can I decode this to String?

Thank you!

Comment: is it japanese? :P try console in your browser: "7b0a2020 22536372 65656e49 4422203a 20224c61 6e64696e 67506167 65564322 2c0a2020 22446576 69636549 4422203a 20224537 45463844 43452d43 4538412d 34463043 2d424243 352d4630 38304332 39464546 3239222c 0a202022 53657373 696f6e53 74617274 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 222c0a20 20225365 7373696f 6e456e64 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 220a7d".split(" ").map(r => String.fromCharCode("0x" + r)).join(" ")

Comment: is thia the response of API?

Comment: this is a request body, please see my answer below for more info.

Comment: It's not `NSString`, it's the result of the `description` property of `NSData` in an `NSLog` expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSData *jsonData;
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]) {
    NSError *error;
    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {

        NSLog(@"json Data %@",error.description);

    } else {

        NSString *JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"JSON String %@",JSONString);//[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"This Data can't be serialized");

}
```

jsonData will be : `<7b0a2020 22536372 65656e49 4422203a 20224c61 6e64696e 67506167 65564322 2c0a2020 22446576 69636549 4422203a 20224537 45463844 43452d43 4538412d 34463043 2d424243 352d4630 38304332 39464546 3239222c 0a202022 53657373 696f6e53 74617274 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 222c0a20 20225365 7373696f 6e456e64 54696d65 22203a20 22323031 342d3033 2d323754 30373a31 343a3336 220a7d>`

Comment: Is this an actual answer to your question or a clarification of your question? If this is a clarification, you should delete this "answer" and put the information in your question.